# Ajax in asp page return 500

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to execute an ajax POST, but always return an 500 Server Error.

For perfom a test, I simplify the request.

Javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
      $("#prova").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Solicitud.aspx/GetDate",
          data: {someParameter: "some value"},
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            console.log("Resposta"+ msg.d);
          }
        });
      });
        });
```

Class Code

```
namespace picovirgiliop
{
    public partial class Solicitud : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetDate(string someParameter)
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
...
```

**EDIT**

POST http://localhost:63010/Solicitud.aspx/GetDate 500 (Internal Server Error)

- send @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9600
- ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9206
- (anonymous) @ Solicitud:300
- dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.js:5183
- elemData.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.js:4991

Comment: Does the response body give you a clue about the error?

Comment: Can you post a screen capture of the response body please

Comment: If I go to the localhost/Solicitud.aspx/GetDate page, its opened the solicitud page and return a 200. Don't return more info that the 500 error, I copy message in edit part.

Comment: Remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` option (you are not stringifying the data)

Comment: If I remove contenttype, doesn't return 500 error, but neither the success console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code review, I can see problem at line

> data: {someParameter: "some value"},

It should be something like below,

```
data: "{ 'someParameter': 'some value' }",
```

OR

```
data: "{ someParameter: 'some value' }",
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify your data which you are passing to the server.  Replace this code `data: {someParameter: "some value"}` with below line of code:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({"someParameter": "some value"}),
```

Comment: the problem is on WebMethod. If I delete string someParameter input parameter, the method is correctly call